# How to get distinct count of rows according to dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Actually, i did counted distinct empid rows according to dates. But the problem is i get only one empid record of that specific dates.Please let me know how to get all empid records. Here is my sql query.

```
$sql = "
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subcount.empid) AS CountOf
     , subcount.name
     , subcount.date
     , subcount.empid
     , calendar.cdate
  FROM subcount
     , calendar
 WHERE subcount.date = calendar.cdate
 GROUP 
    BY subcount.date
";
```

Here is sql database.

For example, When you look at 2020-11-10 there are two empid with 10 and 7.

When i tried to get both records i get only empid 10 record or 7 record, though i need both record counts:

[image: Here is sql database. For example, When you look at 2020-11-10 there are two empid with 10 and 7. When i tried to get both records i get only empid 10 record or 7 record, though i need both record counts]

Here is the output:

[image: Here is the output]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: What does the calendar table look like?

Comment: It is always strange to see people using a join syntax in MySQL that was made redudant before MySQL even existed. Comma-separated joins were used in the 1980s and then it showed they were prone to errors and there was no syntax for outer joins. For these reasons explicit joins (`INNER JOIN``LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.) were introduced in Standard SQL 1992. If you are taught this syntax still, you may want to dismiss the teacher, book or tutorial.

Comment: On a side note: In your sample data some names are consistent (e.g. 10 = Michael) and some are not (29 = hjghjg / hyjghjg / jhjhg / ...). Is there a reason that you are allowing this or is this a flaw in the data model?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY ___` means result rows per ___. If you group by employee ID, you get one row per employee ID. If you want one row per employee ID and date, group by employee ID and date.

```
SELECT any_value(s.name), s.`date`, s.empid, c.cdate, count(*)
FROM subcount s
JOIN calendar c on c.cdate = s.`date`
GROUP BY s.`date`, s.empid
ORDER BY s.`date`, s.empid;
```

I expect a calendar table to have one row per date, so there is exactly one `cdate` for a result row. The `name`, however, can be different from row to row, so we must tell the DBMS, which to pick. With `ANY_VALUE` I tell it that I don't care which.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. but for me this code was fixed 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subcount.id_1) AS CountOf, subcount.name, subcount.date, subcount.empid, calendar.cdate FROM subcount, calendar WHERE subcount.date = calendar.cdate GROUP BY subcount.date, subcount.empid";

Comment: Actually i have two tables(subcount and calendar). I want to count the num of rows where each employee entered data according to daily dates. For example, when employee 10 and employee 7 enter data at 2020-11-10. I need both record counts(row count), the problem is i get only either employee 10 row count or employee 7 row count. The mistake i did at grouping only single table column and count of empid. Now i fixed it. I have a question: without using inner and outer joins, my query creates any problem in future ?

Comment: Once again thanks for your quick response. My best experience though am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: The query you are showing is almost the same query that I suggested. The differences: You are using an antiquated join syntax. It makes no real difference, but you should change it. Just don't use coma-separated joins anymore. You `COUNT(DISTINCT subcount.id_1)`, I `COUNT(*)`. As the IDs are not nullable and unique, we are both simply counting rows, only you make it look like you are doing something more. Use `COUNT( <expression> )` only when the expression can be null and you really want to count non-null values only. Your query is invalid, because you select `subcount.name`...

Comment: ... Your data model allows multiple names per `subcount.date, subcount.empid`, so you must not select *the* `name`. You must pick a particular name instead. If your DBMS runs this query without throwing an error, then you are probably running an old MySQL version without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode. In that case the DBMS silently changes `subcount.name` to `ANY_VALUE(subcount.name)` instead, thus suppressing the error and not telling you that your query is flawed. Apply `ANY_VALUE` yourself explicitly, so your query will run both in future MySQL versions and with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

Comment: As mentioned in the request comments, allowing multiple names per employee ID and date may be unintentional. In that case change your data model. And whatever this decision; as it seems you haven't fully mastered aggregation and `GROUP BY`,I suggest you switch on `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode to have the DBMS help you by detecting invalid queries. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: Sure Thorsten, thanks for suggestion. I am beginner in database. Working on my enhancement. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is to get list of employees with count of their submissions on a given date, this could show do it:

```
SELECT  cnt.empid AS EmpId
        , sc.Name
        , cnt.`date` AS Timestamp
        , cnt.CountOf AS SubmissionCount
FROM    subcount AS sc
INNER JOIN  
(
        SELECT  subcount.empid
                subcount.`date`,
                count(*) AS CountOf 
        FROM        subcount
        INNER JOIN  calendar
        ON      subcount.`date` = calendar.cdate
        GROUP BY 
                subcount.`date`, subcount.empid
)       AS cnt
ON      sc.empid == cnt.empid
```

It uses nested SELECT with GROUP BY to calculate **count per employee (empid) and date (not only employee)**. Outer SELECT join nested SELECT to get subcount.Name piece of data which isn't retrieved in nested SELECT so it needs to be retrieved using outer SELECT.

Comment: Thanks ivan. but for me this code was fixed
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subcount.id_1) AS CountOf, subcount.name, subcount.date, subcount.empid, calendar.cdate FROM subcount, calendar WHERE subcount.date = calendar.cdate GROUP BY subcount.`date`, subcount.`empid`";

Comment: Actually i have two tables(subcount and calendar). I want to count the num of rows where each employee entered data according to daily dates. For example, when employee 10 and employee 7 enter data at 2020-11-10. I need both record counts(row count), the problem is i get only either employee 10 row count or employee 7 row count. The mistake i did at grouping only single table column and count of empid. Now i fixed it. 

I have a question: without using inner and outer joins, my query creates any problem in future ?

Comment: Once again thanks for your quick response. My best experience though am new to stackoverflow.